# Property of null altough variable initialized

Tags: angular

I try to Access a variable in a modal component, but I Always get the error of `Property null toFixed() can't be applied` altough the variable has already been initialized successfully a few lines before. 
That's the specific template:

```
<app-card [hidden]=true>
  <h2>Überblick</h2>
  <div *ngIf="buyingArticles.length > 0">
    <h3>Artikel zum Kauf</h3>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let article of buyingArticles">
        Anzahl: {{article.initialQuantity}}
        Beschreibung: {{article.title}}
        Preis: {{(article.initialQuantity * article.price).toFixed(2)}} €
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Gesamt: {{calculateTotalPrice(buyingArticles).toFixed(2)}} €</h4>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="retourningArticles.length > 0">
    <h3>Artikel zur Retoure</h3>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let article of retourningArticles">
        Anzahl: {{article.initialQuantity}}
        Beschreibung: {{article.title}}
        Preis: {{(article.initialQuantity * article.price).toFixed(2)}} €
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Gesamt: {{calculateTotalPrice(retourningArticles).toFixed(2)}} €</h4>
  </div>
  <h2>Zu zahlen: {{state.adjustedPrice.toFixed(2)}} €</h2>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button (click)="changeStep('scanner')">Weiteren Artikel scannen</button>
    <button (click)="changeStep('payment')">Bezahlung</button>
    <button (click)="showModal = true; state.adjustedPrice=state.totalPrice">Preis anpassen</button>
  </div>
</app-card>
<div *ngIf="showModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button (click)="showModal = false">x</button>
      <h1>Preis anpassen</h1>
      <h2>{{state.adjustedPrice.toFixed(2)}}€</h2>
      <button (click)="calculateDiscount(0.1)">-10%</button>
      <button (click)="calculateDiscount(0.2)">-20%</button>
      <button (click)="calculateDiscount(0.3)">-30%</button>
      <button>Abrunden</button>
      <button (click)="showModal=false; calculateEndSum(calculateTotalPrice(buyingArticles), calculateTotalPrice(retourningArticles))">Bestätigen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like I said before, the first `{{state.adjustedPrive.toFixed(2)}}` Expression is compiled propably, but second one Always throws one error: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of null. And I don't know why. 
The Code from the coresponding ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Article } from 'src/app/model/article';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview.component.css']
})
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() buyingArticles: Array<Article>;
  @Input() retourningArticles: Array<Article>;

  @Output() upcomingStep = new EventEmitter<string>();
  //@Output() totalPrice = new EventEmitter<number>();
  //@Output() adjustedPrice = new EventEmitter<number>()
  @Output() total = new EventEmitter<Object>();

  showModal: boolean = false;
  adjustedPrice: number;

  totalPriceBuyingArticles: number;
  totalPriceRetourningArticles: number;

  state = {
    totalPrice: null,
    adjustedPrice: null,
    difference: null,
    discount: []
  }

  changeStep(upcomingStep: string): void {
    this.upcomingStep.emit(upcomingStep);
  }

  calculateDiscount(amount: number): void {
    this.state.adjustedPrice = this.state.totalPrice * (1 - amount);
    //this.state.totalPrice = this.state.adjustedPrice;
    this.state.difference = this.state.totalPrice - this.state.adjustedPrice;
    this.state.discount.push(amount.toString());
  }

  calculateTotalPrice(arrayToSumUp: Array<Article>): number {
    let totalPrice: number = 0;
    arrayToSumUp.forEach(article => {
      totalPrice = totalPrice + article.price * article.initialQuantity;
    });
    return totalPrice;
  }

  calculateEndSum(): void {
    this.state.adjustedPrice = this.calculateTotalPrice(this.buyingArticles) - this.calculateTotalPrice(this.retourningArticles) - this.state.difference;
    if(this.state.discount.length = 0){
      this.state.totalPrice = this.state.adjustedPrice;
    }

      //this.state.adjustedPrice = this.state.totalPrice;
      this.total.emit(this.state);
      //return this.state.totalPrice.toFixed(2);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calculateEndSum();
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it's just a spelling mistake in template `adjustedPrive` should be adjustedPrice!

Comment: Yes I thought the same, but I can't find adjustedPrive as you say. Where do you read it?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example so we can see exactly where is the issue? https://stackblitz.com/
As from your example, I don't get where the error is.

Comment: You should use in your template state.adjustedPrice?.toFixed(2). When the variable won't be null, the method will be called

Comment: Yes I will create a stackblitz example for you to Show.

Comment: I'm very sorry but to stackblitz this Project it's to complex...I think it has to do something with the LifeCycle of the component...

Comment: I will post some Picture to demonstrate the Problem.

Comment: @andreasteich have you created the stackblitz example?